# Why is this stochastic integral a local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Given a Cadlag local martingale $X$ and a predictable process $H$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^\infty H_t^2d[X,X]_t]<\infty$ how can one show that $(H\cdot X)_t$ is again a local martingale?

Comment: This should follow from the construction of $(H \cdot X)_t$. Which construction are you following?

Comment: You can have a look at the proof of "theorem 5" at this post of George Lowther's blog "almosst sure" :https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/

Comment: @Rhys Steele I learned the construction of the stochastic integral from Protters book  but am not confident in my understanding of it yet. The statement is from the paper "A Guided Tour through Quadratic Hedging" by Schweizer, who refers to a set of french lecture notes for a proof.

Comment: @TheBridge Thanks, I will take a look